# Help Deciphering 2002 Newspaper Kanji

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

Can anyone help me decipher the two middle kanji in the name of this newspaper? The first two are obviously 日本, the last two being 新聞, but I cannot manage to figure out the two others... A Japanese OCR suggested winter solstice as the first of the two, however it split the kanji into two separate characters, and as far as I know, Japanese kanji are not combined into one form very often, if ever at all.

[image: strange shinbun kanji]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 経済{けいざい}

but in [旧字体 (old kanji script system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai)

#### [經](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B6%93)

The 經 also looks like it's a 異体字 (non-standard writing) or in a unique font.

#### [濟](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BF%9F)

Comment: +1, See also: https://www.nikkei.com/